# Laravel "where" clause with "like" comparator

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an array:

```
$box = implode(',', $ch); 

dd($box)
```

That returns:

```
"windows,linux,ios,android"
```

(array can contain 1, 2, 3 or 4 elements like that)

I have this eloquent query:

```
  $vpns = Vpns::where('systemes', 'like', '%'.$box.'%')->get();
```

My problem is that only works if the array contains only one element. If it contains more, it returns nothing.

Comment: Why do you need to implode the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no need to use implode .`wherein` can be better option if you searching exact word.

```
  $vpns = Vpns::whereIn('systemes',$ch)->get();
```

if you still looking for like in query then

```
$vpns = Vpns::where(function($query)use($ch){

         foreach($ch as $value){

           $query->where('systemes', 'like', '%'.$value.'%');

         }
   
         })->get();
```

Updated

```
 Vpns::where(function($query)use($ch){
            foreach($ch as $value){

                $query->orWhere('systemes', 'like', '%'.$value.'%');

            }
        })->orWhere('systemes', 'like', '%'.$box.'%')
            ->where('netflix', '=', $netflix)
            ->where('torrent', '=', $torrent)
            ->where('nolog', '=', $nolog)
            ->where('chine', '=', $chine)
            ->orderBy('prix')->get();
```

Comment: I have no results with whereIn as you said to me

Comment: you should have exact match in systemes  or else it return empty

Comment: if you need  or case then you can use second one but add orwhere  ..  $query->orWhere('systemes', 'like', '%'.$value.'%');

Comment: I dont understand. It works in local but not on production server.

Comment: $vpns = Vpns::whereIn('systemes', $ch)->orWhere('systemes', 'like', '%'.$box.'%')->where('netflix', '=', $netflix)->where('torrent', '=', $torrent)->where('nolog', '=', $nolog)->where('chine', '=', $chine)->orderBy('prix')->get();

Comment: as i said earlier if you use wherein then you should have exact value in systemes or else it return empty . if no exact match then you have to use second query mentioned

Comment: Vpns::where(function($query)use($ch){

            foreach($ch as $value){

                $query->orWhere('systemes', 'like', '%'.$value.'%');

            }

        })
            ->orWhere('systemes', 'like', '%'.$box.'%')
            ->where('netflix', '=', $netflix)
            ->where('torrent', '=', $torrent)
            ->where('nolog', '=', $nolog)
            ->where('chine', '=', $chine)
            ->orderBy('prix')->get();

Answer (score 1):

you may need to put your conditions in an `or` logical connection

```php
$vpns = Vpns::where(function($q) use ($ch) {
  foreach ($ch as $system) {
    $q->orWhere('systemes', 'like', '%' . $system . '%');
  }
})->get();
```

Comment: What's the point of `$vpns = Vpns::query();`? This can simply be `$vpns = Vpns::where(function(q) use ($ch){ ... })->get();` I'm seeing this pop up more and more on Stackoverflow, the use of `::query()` where it is completely unnecessary 

Comment: I agree that in this specific instance is unnecessary. The fact is, I started the answer by thinking to write directly the foreach, and in that case the separation of the query was required.  Only afterwards I added the `where` callback and i rendered the first line unnecessary

Comment: Ah, gotcha; that makes more sense  Wasn't saying there was anything wrong with your answer btw, was just curious if I was missing a convention movement to always using `::query()`, or if it was just a coincidence, etc. Cheers!